# Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter on $X$. $\mathcal{B} \subseteq P( X)$ is called a filter- base........

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

Let  $\mathcal{F}$  be a filter on $X$. $\mathcal{B} \subseteq P( X)$ is called a filter- base satisfies bellow conditions:

( 1 ) :
‎$ ‎\mathcal{B}‎ ‎\neq‎ ‎\emptyset‎ $‏

‎‎( 2 ) :
‎$ ‎\emptyset ‎\not\in  ‎\mathcal{B}‎   $‎

‎‎‎( 3 ) : ‎‎if $ A , B ‎‎‎‎‎\in‎ ‎\mathcal{‎B}‎ $ , then there is a ‎‎$ C‎ ‎\in‎ ‎\mathcal{‎B}‎ $ s.t ‎$ C‎ ‎‎\subseteq A‎ ‎‎\cap ‎B‎ $‎.‎‎‎‎
‎

Are  The following conditions  equivalent?Why?

> (1) X is compact.
>
> (2) Each ultrafilter in $X$ has a limit.
>
> (3) If $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter-base of closed subsets of $X$, then $\cap \mathcal{F} \not= ∅$.

Comment: Just for reference: A filter base $\mathcal B$ must (1) be non-empty, (2) not contain the empty set, (3) satisfy that for any two $U, V$ in $\mathcal B$ there must be a $W$ in $\mathcal B$ such that $W \subseteq U \cap V$. Then you can say that $\mathcal B$ is a filter base for $\mathcal F$ when $\mathcal F$ is the set of supersets of elements of $\mathcal B$. Or equivalently that it's the intersection of all filters containing $\mathcal B$. Or again equivalently that it's the smallest filter containing $\mathcal B$.

Comment: @Daniel: Alireza defined *filter base*, not *base for the filter* $\mathscr{F}$, so the definition is correct as stated; it’s the mention of $\mathscr{F}$ that doesn’t belong.

Comment: @Alireza: Yes, the three statements are equivalent; you can find proofs in many places on the net. See, for instance, Theorem $15.3$ of [this PDF](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf).

Comment: Is it right for (2 $‎\Longrightarrow$ 1) if $\mathcal{V}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover. Hence $\{X - V : V \in \mathcal{V} \}$ is a **filter-base**. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an ultrafilter
such that $\{X - V : V \in \mathcal{V} \}$. So, $\mathcal{F}$ has a limit point $x$. But $x \not\in V$ for any $V \in \mathcal{V}$, otherwise $V$ would be a neighborhood of $x$ and $V \in \mathcal{F}$. However,
this is a contradiction with $X - V \in \mathcal{F}$."Could you give me some guide for (1 $‎\Longrightarrow$ 2)?

Comment: (3) is related to this fact: $X$ is compact if and only if every family of closed set in $X$, which has [finite intersection property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property), has non-empty intersection.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Check [revision 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/508753/1), it was nothing like correct when I made the (obsolete, now) comment.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, yes, that does make a difference. I’d not realized that so much had been changed before I saw it.